# Why does the "GetDeviceCaps" Function always return exactly half of the size of my screen?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++20

I've been trying to get the screen size with <Windows.h>'s `GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), HORZRES)` function, but whenever I run the code, it always returns exactly half of my screen resolution.

Does anyone know why this may happen to my computer? It works fine on most other monitors.

My screen resolution is (2736x1824) (surface pro).

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    HDC display = GetDC(NULL);
    const int x = GetDeviceCaps(display, HORZRES), y = GetDeviceCaps(display, VERTRES); //returns (1368, 912)
    std::cout << x << ", " << y << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process

Comment: but you can't use "windows.h" stuff in `main()` . It needs `WinMain()`

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин "*but you can't use "windows.h" stuff in `main()` . It needs `WinMain()`*" - that is completely wrong. Console apps on Windows are full Windows apps, they have complete access to the entire Win32 API.

Comment: @RemyLebeau no, not full. Say it can't use regular COM because these apps doesn't have message pump where real ones do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau can have? example please . MT COM's has own pump so are suitable on that

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин a message pump is nothing more than a loop that calls `(Peek|Get)Message()` and `DispatchMessage()`. A COM message pump may also involve `CoWaitForMultipleHandles()`, as well. There is nothing stopping a console app from calling these functions, the exact same way a GUI app would. COM objects can be created and used in console apps just fine. STAs and MTAs work in console apps just fine.

Comment: @RemyLebeau STAs ... work in console apps just fine? i don't think so.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин with the proper code, yes they do. But I'm not having this discussion with you anymore. It has nothing to do with the question at hand. I'm done with this line of commenting. If you don't believe me, feel free to post your own question about it.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин every statement you just made is wrong. I'm done commenting with you.

Comment: even COM itself can't do it without creating a hidden window (i don't mean just a window with `SW_HIDE`  turned on).

Comment: @Але There is a **single** difference between applications that target the CONSOLE subsystem and applications that target the WINDOWS subsystem: The system allocates a console when launching the former, but will not when launching the latter. And that is literally all the differences there are. COM works in a console application, you can have STAs, an MTA, or ASTAs, you can register and create windows or dialogs. It can be DPI-aware or choose not to be. *Everything* works the same way.

Comment: looks like this thing  IInspectable does accept my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is almost certainly 'suffering' from [DPI Awareness issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows).

Running your code on my system presents similar issues; however, adding a call to the [`SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setthreaddpiawarenesscontext) resolves the problem:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE); // This line fixes the issue.
    HDC display = GetDC(NULL);
    const int x = GetDeviceCaps(display, HORZRES), y = GetDeviceCaps(display, VERTRES); //returns (1368, 912)
    std::cout << x << ", " << y << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Without that added call, the program shows output of "1536, 864". With it added, I see the (correct) values: "1920, 1080".

Comment: same with you You can't use "windows.h" stuff like that

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин Why not?

Comment: beacause it's not for console apps

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин Where does it say that console apps don't have access to "kernel32.dll" or "User32.dll"? Even your answer uses functions declared in Windows.h.

Comment: my answer is for gui code. Which is to say you can't use dc stuff from console app

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин Well, I've been doing so for many years ... and the code sample I posted works without problem. Also, there are *many* answers here on Stack Overflow that use DCs and other "windows.h" stuff in console-based `int main()` applications.

Comment: and what you usually do with these dc's? one example? haha for many years

Comment: yeah looks like you can do it now

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин console apps on Windows have had full access to the Win32 API for a very long time, at least since the days of NT/XP when Windows was no longer built on top of DOS and the console became a normal Win32 app emulating DOS.

Comment: @RemyLebeau my book is win95 programming haha