# Why does BitBlt() Zoom in when copying the exact same pixels from the same bitmap onto itself?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi, bitblt

I'm trying to make a window that copies the desktop, and mess around with the pixels on it. I do this by using BitBlt from the Desktop Handle to my Window handle. This works as expected -  a window is created which looks exactly like the desktop. However, when I use BitBlt() again to move a segment of pixels from my Window to another area of my Window, the pixels are zoomed in. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Here is the code, I have commented on the section where the issue seems to be coming from:

```
#include <windows.h>

int myWidth, myHeight;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HDC DhWnd = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
        HDC MhWnd = GetDC(hwnd);
        BitBlt(MhWnd, 0, 0, myWidth, myHeight, DhWnd, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
        BitBlt(MhWnd, 300, 0, 100, 500, MhWnd, 300, 0, SRCCOPY);

        /*^^^^ The above segment zooms in the pixels despite copy pasting the EXACT
       SAME coordinates of the bitmap onto itself. ^^^^*/


        ReleaseDC(hwnd, DhWnd);
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, MhWnd);
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_PAINT:
        ValidateRect(hwnd, NULL);
        return 0;

    case WM_CLOSE:
    case WM_DESTROY:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

}



int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    RECT Drc;
    MSG msg;
    HWND DhWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    HWND MyhWnd;
    GetWindowRect(DhWnd, &Drc);
    myWidth = Drc.right - Drc.left;
    myHeight = Drc.bottom - Drc.top;


    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = NULL;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = "MyWindow";


    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    MyhWnd = CreateWindow("MyWindow", NULL, WS_POPUP, 0, 0, myWidth, myHeight, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (MyhWnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }


    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: ... but your problem most likely stems from not using DPI awareness.

Comment: Set the app's manifest to use DPI awareness: "Project->Properties->Manifest->Input and Output->DPI Awareness" and select "High" or "Per monitor".

Comment: Or set your Windows to use a plain, 100% zoom factor for the desktop display? Otherwise, the OS is scaling the desktop but not your own bitmaps/DCs.

Comment: @AdrianMole Edited the HWND to HDC in the code. Thanks so much, changing the DPI awareness to HIGH has fixed the issue! Could you recommend some resources that go more in depth on the reasoning behind all of this?  I will attempt to read the Microsoft Documentation to try figure it out.

Comment: I can't really find an *exact* duplicate question (there may be one) but this is related: [Why does the "GetDeviceCaps" Function always return exactly half of the size of my screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68429406/10871073)

Comment: You're releasing `DhWnd` using the wrong window parameter.